# Finding a DOM element from an event sent over web sockets

Tags: javascript, events, dom, websocket

So I have two browser windows with identical DOMs that are connected by websockets over a server.

On every `click` event, the event is `JSON.stringify`ed, sent to the other window and then de-stringified.

**On the other window, how can I dispatch that exact event on the same element that the event was fired on the other window?**

The `target` property contains all the same information as it did before it was sent, but of course, its link to a real DOM element has been lost over web sockets.

Because the browsers can be of different sizes, I can't use `document.elementFromPoint`.

Comment: Can you add a unique id to all DOM elements? that would make it trivial to handle. Include the id in the web socket message and on the receiving side just lookup the element with the given id.